# sitemesh and spring: only index.jsp is decorated

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, sitemesh

I'm trying to include sitemesh to my spring-mvc web-application.
I added this to my web.xml:

```
<filter>
<filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
<filter-class>com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.filter.PageFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

My decorators.xml-file:

```
<decorators defaultdir="/WEB-INF/decorators">
    <decorator name="master" page="master.jsp">
        <pattern>/</pattern>
    </decorator>
</decorators>
```

And the master.jsp-file:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="decorator" uri="http://www.opensymphony.com/sitemesh/decorator" %>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>
        :: LiVis :: <decorator:title /> ::
    </title>
    <style type="text/css">@import "resources/css/generalStyle.css";</style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="header">
                <div id="headerPicture">
                    <img id="livis" src="resources/images/village.png" alt="livis" />
                </div>
                <div id="headerMenu">
                    <ul id="navigation">
                        <li><a href="admin/insertEntryForm.html">Insert</a></li>
                        <li>Table-View</li>
                        <li>Graph-View</li>
                        <li>About</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="main">
                <decorator:body />
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I thougt, that the master.jsp would be applied to every page in my webapp, but it is only done with the index.jsp.
To óther jsp-files, which are in some folders in WEB-INF/views (see the picture) it is not done.
[image: folder-structure in WEB-INF]

What could be the reason for this?
Thank you!!

**Edit**

A page in the vwies/admin-folder:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Registration Page</title>
</head>
<body>

<form:form method="POST" action="/LiteratureVisualization/admin/insertTest" modelAttribute="object">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>First name:</td>
            <td><form:input path="author.firstname" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Last name:</td>
            <td><form:input path="author.lastname" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Title:</td>
            <td><form:input path="publication.title" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Subtitle:</td>
            <td><form:input path="publication.subtitle" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Abstract:</td>
            <td><form:input path="publication.abstr" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Year of Launch:</td>
            <td><form:input path="publication.launchYear" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Month of Launch:</td>
            <td><form:input path="publication.launchMonth" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Volume:</td>
            <td><form:input path="publication.volume" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Number:</td>
            <td><form:input path="publication.number" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Sort of:</td>
            <td><form:input path="publication.sortOf" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Published In:</td>
            <td><form:input path="publication.publishedIn" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Register"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use /* instead of / in your pattern declaration.

Or if it doesn't solve the problem, look at your jsp files and check that you have html and body tags into it. If not, sitemesh can't replace the tag with ones declared in your decorator.

Comment: This didn't work... is it possible, tha the jsp's in tha admin, browse, general and graph-folder can't be found?

Comment: could you edit your post and show us a page into this folder ? Have you tried to add a pattern like : /views/admin/* to test if this is a path problem or a jsp problem ?